# How does the empirical correlation function differ from R's ACF() function?

Tags: estimation, autocorrelation, covariance

I'm wondering which one is better to use, and why?

By empirical correlation I mean $\rho(h) = \gamma(h)/\gamma(0)$

Where $\gamma(h) = \frac{1}{n-h} \sum_{i=1}^{n-h} (X_i - \bar{X})(X_{i+h}-\bar{X})$

As far as I can tell the empirical covariance function is an attempt to actually estimate the covariance of $X_i$ and $X_{i+h}$, assuming it's stationary. Reading the R documentation it's not clear to me how ACF() obtains its estimate. They give different answers, so clearly there is at least one difference in their methodology.

Does anyone have any insight on when to use which method?

Comment: where does it say that?

Comment: Sorry it seems I misread, that was the partial autocorrelation. Fixed. Still, they give different estimates, so what exactly is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The estimator given by most textbooks and the one used by the `acf` function in R is
$$
\hat\gamma_h = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^{n-h} (X_i - \bar{X})(X_{i+h}-\bar{X}).
$$
Note how it has $n$ instead of $n-h$ in the denominator.

This estimator has the advantage that the estimated autocovariance function is always positive semi-definite (unlike the estimator you propose).  See e.g. [Wei 2007](https://www.google.no/search?q=wei%20time%20series%20analysis%20filetype%3Apdf&oq=wei&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j35i39j0l4.2493j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), ch. 2.5.2.